# Visual Studio 2010 Code Editor Outlining Icons?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, icons, code-editor

I've seen a lot of videos where the presenter has little icons next to their outlining in code  as shown in the below screenshot:

[image: Visual Studio 2010 code editor icons]

I'm guessing this is a plugin as I can't find any info in the VS documentation how to to enable such functionality.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [VS10x Editor View Enhancer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34eee02b-f1f6-433a-b210-62e94c0bcb87) plugin.